# If Eucalyptus Cluster controller crashs what will happen?

Tags: controller, cloud, cluster-computing, eucalyptus

I have 2 physical machines.
If I make cloud computing with Eucalyptus :

- First physical machine will be Cloud controller, Cluster controller and Walrus controller
- Second physical machine will be Node controller

If first physical machine crashs what will happen to my virtual machines without Cluster controller ?
If second physical machine crashs what will happen to my virtual machines without Node controller ?

Answer (score 1):

If first physical machine crashes, the VMs running on NC will be still alive. But if there are any volume attached to VM through EBS (provided by SC/Walrus running on first machine), the volume could not be accessible.

If NC/second machine crashes, All VMs running on this host will die!!

Hope this help